# Find x respectively y in two sequences sharing terms - An arithmetic and geometric problem

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

Problem:

Two different sequences contains both *a* and *b*.

Sequence ..., -1, *a*, *b*, *x*,... is arithmetic.

Sequence ..., *y*, *a*, *b*; 12,5;... is geometric.

determine *x* and *y*.

---

I have been asked by a member of the mathoverflow to post here.

I have been going at this problem for several hours and haven't made any, in my opinion, real progress.

I welcome any solution to the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Let the common ratio of arithmetic progression be $d$.

$d=a+1=b-a=x-b$

Let the common ratio of geometric progression be $r$.

$r= \frac{a}{y}= \frac{b}{a}= \frac{12}{b}= \frac{5}{12}$

which gives $b= \frac{144}{5} \implies a= \frac{1728}{25} \implies y= \frac{20736}{125}.$

Now, the value of $b-a$ and $a+1$ do not match. Therefore, the question seems to be incorrect.